# Difference between these 2 scenarios in load testing

Tags: .net, jmeter, load-testing

I'm creating a load test, and I have done this so far:
threads-100
ramp up period- 100
loop - 2

My understanding is that 1 thread will be fired per second, and after the first batch of 100 threads is done, another round of 100 threads will be fired in the same way, with the difference between their firing period as 1 sec(same as the first loop). Is this correct?
Also, what would be the case if I had this:

threads-200
ramp up period- 200
loop-1

Does it mean 1 thread per second and a total of 200 threads? Is this equivalent to the 1st case? Please help, I'm getting very wierd results while testing, hence this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. 2nd scenario is not the same as the first.

Remember these (assuming 'delay thread creation until needed' is selected)

```
Thread Creation Rate = ( Ramp up Period ) / (No of Threads).
Thread is executed independently.
```

**First Scenario:**

Thread Creation Rate = 1 thread / sec. Every second, a thread is created. So after 100 sec, you will have 100 threads/users.

Once the first thread is created, it sends the first the request. once it completes, it does not wait unless you have have explicitly set a timer. Since the loop count is 2, it sends another request. Here, each user sends 2 requests to the server. But the second request is sent only after the first request is complete. but it does not matter other threads have the sent the requests/got their responses or not.

**Second Scenario:**

Thread Creation Rate = 1 thread / sec. So after 200 sec, you will have 200 threads/users.
Here each sends only one request to the server.

What is the difference?

Lets assume, the server usually takes 300 seconds to process a request.

**First Scenario:**

After 100 seconds, 100 users have sent requests to the server. As each request is processed in 300 seconds, after 100 seconds,  100 users wait for the server to respond. They do not send any other request until any of the users got a response. Even after 200 seconds, the serer has only 100 concurrent users.

**Second Scenario:**

But, here, The server has 200 concurrent users after 200 seconds. we have more load on the server compared to the first scenario. Response time of the server might be more compared to the First scenario as the load is more.

Comment: I have another question-
What if I go on increasing the number of users, while also increasing the ramp-up period to be equal to the number of users, and the loop count remains 2? In this case, will the load on my service increase/remain the same/decrease? I had done that expected the load to increase, but it's decreasing!..something like 100-100-2,then 200-200-2..etc

Comment: Also, in the first scenario, there will be only 100 unique users, each sending a request which is = loop count, whereas in the 2nd scenario, the number of unique users will be 200?

Comment: Yes. No of thread is no of users. Lets assume the request takes only 1 second to complete. In this case, the first user sends a first request once the test is started, next second he sends another request (as the loop count is 2)...it happens in the first 2 second itself. ..even before other threads are created, first user has done   with his requests and first thread does not send any more requests. a load on the server also gets reduced. So you can not expecte 100 concurrent users in your scenario.