# Difference between Jmeter load test scenarios

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am testing asp.net website using Jmeter. I have used below scenarios to load test. Scenario 1 give me correct result(What I expect and can be wrong) and Scenario 2 is not giving same result. But I have used same number of requests within same time. Can someone explain me why is this?

Scenario 1.
[image]

Scenario 2.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ramp up](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) time does not determine when any of your tests are going to complete.  It only controls when your test is going to start.

Also, the number of threads any test can create concurrently is limited to the memory you've allocated to JMeter.  Even though you've set the thread count to 60000, if you've hit the maximum memory you've allocated, the threads will either queue up or never generate (you can watch the JMeter logs for thread creating or errors).

I recommend tuning your JMeter instance so you have some stability to your tests, here's a good guide. [LINK](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/)

Answer (score 0):

No of requests you have sent might be same. But the concurrent user load on the server is completely different.

I had clarified similar question few weeks ago. You can check the answer here.

[Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741713/difference-between-these-2-scenarios-in-load-testing/23748145#23748145)